# OpenStreetMap [mapbox] don't hide roads on zoom

Tags: zooming, openstreetmap, mapbox

I'm trying to style a mapbox in "Mapbox Studio", but i can't get the solution of block zoom in/out.

I want to show the same roads (not less) behind zoom12 and zoom11. It's not about stylesheet, i mean its some defeault options of openstreetmap and maybe some1 know how to resolve it.

Comment: Sure it's about stylesheet. That's where you define which things are visible on which zoom level. It's not a "default option of openstreetmap" because OSM doesn't know about zoom levels, it's just a large database.

Comment: Ye, it's about default stylesheet. But I have to define each class #road[class='service'], #road[class='secondary'] because: #road and [zoom=11] {line-width: 1}, [zoom=12] { line-width:1} etc... isnt working..